# Placing Content in mat card

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, angular-material, mat-card

I am new to frontend development and learning and practising CSS. I am using a mat card as shown in attached image[image: myCSS]

My code is as follows

```
   <div class="col-4">
                        <mat-card class="card">
                                <div class="header">
                                    <div class="content1">Content of My header</div>
                                    <div class="content2">Content of My header</div>
                                </div>
             
                                <button mat-button>MyButton</button>
                        </mat-card>
                    </div>

.card {
  background-color: red
  height: 47vh;
  display: flex;
  top: 2.5rem;
  flex-direction: column;
  right: 2rem;
}

.header {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 3% 0% 1% 3%;
}
```

If we see Header is leaving spaces on all three sides. I want to cover entire header with red color without leaving these sides. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Change the .card css to:

```
  .card {
    background-color: red
    height: 47vh;
    display: flex;
    top: 2.5rem;
    flex-direction: column;
    right: 2rem;
    padding:0; <------Add this line
  }
```

Comment: Because of padding :0 button also sticking to all 4 corners. I don't want button ton be attached to corners like header. How can I do that? –

Comment: put the button in a container div and give the container a padding.

Comment: You could also just put a margin on the button.

Answer (score 0):

try margin:0 inside .card class

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend you adding a reset style file to your website. Every browser has got different default settings and it will prevent having styling differences in the future. This is a basic way how to do this:

**HTML:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/reset-css/reset.css" />
```

**CSS:**

```
@import '/path/to/reset-css/reset.css';
```

**Example in your code:**

```css
@import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css';
.wrapper{
  height: 47vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.header{
   background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 90%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="content1">Content of My header</div>
            <div class="content2">Content of My header</div>
        </div>

        <button>MyButton</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Because of padding :0 button also sticking to all 4 corners. I don't want button ton be attached to corners like header. How can I do that?

Comment: @Rocky your button component is inside the parent container which has the property `display: flex` that's why it has got the same size as other components. I modified your structure, let me know if it is fine.